# My SQL INSERT INTO based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table called autosaves where i my web-app saves every 4 second a user autosave in case my web-app crashes.

**autoSaves**

- customerId
- designType
- autosaveFile

The condition is this:

If a customerId and designtype already exists, update the row with these values(customerId designType autosaveFile)

otherwise if the 2 conditions i mentioned do not exist then create a new row with the new values.

I have come accross the Insert Into statement but i cannot seem to understand how to formulate it so that it updates when the 2 conditions are met.

Comment: What is your key? I think you can only use INSERT INTO for updating when there is a key conflict.

Comment: autosaveId ? i am trying to understand how it would work to be honest, i have never touched Mysql and i am building a web-app using pen and paper. Oops you got me. Any ideas now?

Comment: You could try the old-fashioned way: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx (pretty much IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT).

Comment: If..Exists..Where, that i get it, it searches all rows in the table autosaves, but the next statement has this     UPDATE table1 SET (..) WHERE ',  what do i put in the brackets?

Comment: You think you can create a webapp when you don't know anything about mysql? Seems like you'll be posting questions every hour or two, effectively getting SO to write the app for you.

Comment: nah the reason is something else. I have a developer who is doing it for me i just want to provide some primitive documentantion ''requirements'' for him and i got carried away into the details that are needed to write down. hey i'm learning something at least no?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Actually use the answer you already accepted :P Did not know ON DUPLICATE KEY also accepts indexes, so that would be the best way to do it.

Comment: will do man, thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a unique index on the `customerId` and `designType` columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_cust_design ON autoSaves (customerId, designType);
```

Then you can use the following `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO autoSaves (customerId, designType, autosaveFile)
VALUES (@id, @type, @file)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE autosaveFile = VALUES(autosaveFile)
```

Comment: do i need to create a unique everytime an autosave is created?

Comment: No, that's part of the database schema, you just do it once.

Comment: one last thing. Does this statement traverse the whole autosave table to detect the duplicate keys? From what i've read the  IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT statement loops over all records so it does have a performance hit. I'm not building the new Space Shutlle but i am just wondering.

Comment: No, that's the whole point of an index -- it makes searching efficient. That's generic database technology, not anything specific to MySQL.